# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, sphinxql

I installed Foolz SphinxQL Query Builder for PHP with composer using the following json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "foolz/sphinxql-query-builder": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

My php is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL;
use Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// create a SphinxQL Connection object to use with SphinxQL
$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setConnectionParams('127.0.0.1', 9306);

$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('*')
    ->from('test1')
    ->match('@test document');
#    ->where('banned', '=', 1);

$result = $query->execute();

var_dump($result);

?>
```

Using my debugger I see the autoloader (function `findFileWithExtension`) is trying to find the file at `/mnt/i/var/www/vhosts/my.play.net/sphinx/vendor/composer/../foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/Connection.php` when it should presumably be looking in `/mnt/i/var/www/vhosts/my.play.net/sphinx/vendor/composer/../foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/Drivers/Mysqli/Connection.php` where it is actually located.

Can anyone advise why I might be seeing this and how I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using incorrect namespace. To get `vendor/foolz/sphinxql-query-builder/src/Drivers/Mysqli/Connection.php` you need to use `Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\Mysqli\Connection` as FQN:

```
use Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL;
use Foolz\SphinxQL\Drivers\Mysqli\Connection;
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm new to it and was using the example given on their web page http://foolcode.github.io/SphinxQL-Query-Builder/.

Comment: This is probably documentation for 1.x line, something have been changed in 2.x line.